# How to get the simple query executed in Laravel 5? DB:: getQueryLog giving array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, laravel

I am Fresher in Laravel and I want to get the simple  query executed in Laravel 5. I am using below function for inserting  data

```
    public function store12($inputs)
    {
        $this->name = $inputs['name'];
        $this->email = $inputs['email'];
        $this->text = $inputs['message'];       
        $this->save();
         echo "<pre>"; print_r(dd(DB::getQueryLog()));
        //echo DB::table('contacts')->toSql();
        die;

    }
```

And use this:- **dd(DB::getQueryLog())** for get the row query this is giving raw query below:-

```
array:1
  0 => array:3
    "query" => "insert into `contacts` (`name`, `email`, `text`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:5
      0 => "shahjad"
      1 => "shahjad.ahmadtimt@gmail.com"
      2 => "xsxdxsda"
      3 => "2016-06-13 12:17:43"
      4 => "2016-06-13 12:17:43"
    ]
    "time" => 33.0
  ]
]
```

Actually I want to query like this:-

```
insert into `contacts` (`name`, `email`, `text`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('shahjad', 'shahjad.ahmadtimt@gmail.com', 'xsxdxsda', '2016-06-13 12:17:43', '2016-06-13 12:17:43')"
```

so that i easily execute this query into phpmyadmin directly otherwise I have to mention the value into the query which is time consuming.

In Codeigniter when we use last_query method it display a simple query without array. I want to same like codeigniter. Is it possible or not

Answer (score 0):

use ->tosql()

exemple

```
  dd(DB::select('users')->where('smthing',1)->get()->tosql());
```

**Edit**

```
 $test = DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['name' => $inputs['name'], 'email' => $inputs['email'], 'text' => $inputs['message']]
  )->tosql();
```

or you can do this

```
\DB::listen(function($sql) {
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

or

you can use this package , it will show you every sql query has been made
[**laravel-debugbar**](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: :- Actually, I want to the Insert Query

Comment: :- I edited  question and i want to query for insertion for direct use the query into phpmyadmin for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  **raw** method

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("
                               insert into `contacts` 
                               (`name`, `email`, `text`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
                              values
                              ('shahjad', 'shahjad.ahmadtimt@gmail.com', 'xsxdxsda', '2016-06-13 12:17:43', '2016-06-13 12:17:43')
                             " ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked for me, please try

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

then

```
run your query
```

then

```
foreach (DB::getQueryLog() as $q) {
  $queryStr = \Str::replaceArray('?', $q['bindings'], $q['query']);
  echo $queryStr . ";\n";
}
```